# Storing object pointers for both quick access and on-demand sorted-ness?

Tags: c++, vector, maps

I needed a program for a school project that allowed for the following functionality:

-dynamic object creation thus used c++ keyword:

```
new
```

-display a sorted a bunch of objects based on a different member variables. 
-quick access to dynamically created objects.

I order to do this I used a map that stored a string key and a pointer to an object.  This allowed for quick access and lookup of individual objects by key.

To solve the on-demand sort functionality required, I iterated through the map and added the second element--which was the object pointer--to a vector.  I then sorted the vector using a lambda function based on the sorted-ness the user specified.

Comment: The more specific the more likely it will be answered. But English is a poor way to explain code. Code is much more precise. Show the code and show what you would like to achieve.

Comment: If you don't need the insertion to be fast you can build all potential sorting maps ahead of time but have them use an index into the actual object `vector` as their key. Then you can just use the appropriate `map` for lookup which will be very fast.

Comment: @JonathanMee Thank you Jonathan but at the time of the project insertion and access needed to be fast.  In fact those were prioritized in the spec of the assignment.

Comment: Let's say you have *a* different arrangements that you'll need to sort for. You can either construct all the sorts on insertion which will take *O(a \* log(n))* to insert and *O(log(n))* to lookup. Or you can sort lazily which will take *O(log(n))* time to insert and *O(n \* log(n))* to look up. Personally I'd expect my suggestion to be the faster of the 2, it's certainly going to be the simpler of the 2.

Comment: @JonathanMee I had objects each with four variables that could be compared.  So a user could ask to see a sorted output of any of those 4 ways.  i also needed fast map lookup for an individual object.  Map lookup and access is O(logN), a key, object pair.  Storing in a vector to allow sorting was just a push_back is constant.  Sorting is O(nLogn), Iteration through the vector is O(N).  The point of the project was to allow a user to enter a predefined key and find the object.  Looking up in a map was one thing, displaying in sorted fashion was another.  Sorting was easiest to do with a vector.

Comment: You're right, I should have said that insertion under your method was *O(1)* time not *O(log(n))* time... Sorting your vector will invalidate your map's indexing, so don't do that... With 4 possible sorting arrangements you should *definitely* be sorting on insertion. *a* is almost negligible.